# BizTalk server2010 supported ciphers

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

We got vulnerabilities on windows server 2008R2, we are using BizTalk server 2010, they are going to disable RC4 ciphers, However how do we check what are all the ciphers our BizTalk server supporting and where do we find those list.

Answer (score 0):

Basically they are going to be disabling TLS 1.0.

What you need to do is install the .NET Framework v4.5.2, as the actually ciphers you are talking about are at the .Net layer rather than in BizTalk.

Then you need to set the registry keys to disable TLS 1.0 and enable it defaulting to a stronger cryptography.

There is a good article about "[BizTalk Server 2010 and support for TLS 1.2](https://www.codit.eu/blog/biztalk-server-2010-and-support-for-tls-12/)"

Answer (score 0):

Well, hold on.  They are only 'vulnerabilities' if you're actually using them.

If you have no TLS(SSL) 1.0 endpoints (Receive Locations), you don't have a problem.

If you are calling TLS(SSL) 1.0 endpoints (Send Ports), then your trading partner needs to update first, then you can move to TLS >1.0.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response